# Transfer UTF-8 file over FTP using ASCII mode?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, ftp, ascii

The question says it all. Is it possible to transfer a UTF-8 file over FTP using ASCII mode? Or will this cause the characters to be written incorrectly? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. UTF-8 encoding was designed to be backward compatible with ASCII encoding.
2. The [RFC 959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959) requires the FTP clients and servers to treat the file in ASCII mode as 8-bit:

   > 3.1.1.1.  ASCII TYPE
   >
   > ...
   >
   > The sender converts the data from an internal character
   > representation to the standard 8-bit NVT-ASCII
   > representation (see the Telnet specification).  The receiver
   > will convert the data from the standard form to his own
   > internal form.
   >
   > In accordance with the NVT standard, the  sequence
   > should be used where necessary to denote the end of a line
   > of text.  (See the discussion of file structure at the end
   > of the Section on Data Representation and Storage.)
   >
   > ...
   >
   > Using the standard NVT-ASCII representation means that data
   > must be interpreted as 8-bit bytes.

---

So even UTF-8 unaware FTP client or server should correctly translate line-endings, as these are encoded identically in ASCII and UTF-8. And they should not corrupt the other characters.

---

From a practical point of view: I haven't met a server that does have problems with 8-bit text files. I'm Czech, so I regularly work with UTF-8 and in past with Windows-1250 and ISO/IEC 8859-2 8-bit encodings.

Answer (score -2):

[RFC 2640](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2640), from 1999, updates the FTP protocol to support internationalization. It requires FTP servers to use UTF-8 as the transfer encoding in section 2.2. So as long as you aren't trying to upload to a [DEC TOPS-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOPS-20) server (which [stores five 7-bit bytes within a 36-bit word](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/3_DataTransfer.html)), you should be fine.

Comment: The RFC 2640 is about file name encoding, not file contents.